# Zero-copy convert slice of integers to slice of bytes

Tags: rust

How to convert e.g. `&[u64]` to `&[u8]`? I contend that it's safe to do with this method (edited to make harder to misuse):

```
use num_traits::PrimInt;

/// Reinterpret a slice of T as a slice of bytes without copying.
/// Only use with simple copy types like integers, floats, bools, etc. Don't use with structs or enums.
pub fn get_bytes<T: PrimInt>(array: &[T]) -> &[u8] {
    // Add some checks to try and catch unsound use
    debug_assert!(size_of::<T>() <= 16);
    debug_assert!(size_of::<T>().is_power_of_two());
    debug_assert_eq!(size_of::<T>(), align_of::<T>());
    // Safety: &[u64] can be safely converted to &[u8]
    // (so why doesn't rust have a safe method for this?)
    unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(array.as_ptr() as *const u8, array.len() * std::mem::size_of::<T>()) }
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8f30b03d44aadd6c720057337ac41236

That's how it would be written in C or C++. It's not safe to do the inverse conversion, because the alignment of the types differs. But casting down into a slice of bytes works, and it's why you can cast everything to `char*` in C.

Does Rust expose a safe method to do this? I'm currently just using the code above, but it'd be nice to get rid of one more unsafe block if I can. If not, why not? Is it unsafe for some reason I haven't considered?

Comment: I think your method is unsound because of alignment & endiannes issues. What if T is 3 bytes wide but requires 4 byte alignment?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [`bytemuck` crate](https://github.com/Lokathor/bytemuck) for a well-defined way to do this safely.

Comment: @cafce25 then the assertion panics

Comment: It needs to be a proper `assert!` else you're still allowing UB in safe code.

Comment: I think the compiler can optimize the asserts away, since they're known at compile time. But the bytemuck crate works better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck) crate is the crate for this kind of things. It has the [`cast_slice()`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/fn.cast_slice.html) function for that:

```rust
pub fn get_bytes<T: bytemuck::NoUninit>(array: &[T]) -> &[u8] {
    bytemuck::cast_slice(array)
}
```

However, your function is unsound: it allows calling with types with padding bytes, but reinterpreting padding bytes (essentially `uninit`) as `u8` is UB. `bytemuck::cast_slice()` prohibits this by requiring the type to implement `NoUninit`. You can `#[derive(NoUninit)]` for your types, as long as they satisfy [all requirements](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/trait.NoUninit.html).

Comment: Good to know about that crate. Still seems odd rust doesn't support something like that in the standard library. I agree about the unsoundness, that's why the comment reads "Only use with simple copy types like integers, floats, bools, etc. Don't use with structs or enums." I just don't know of a way to enforce that.

Comment: @Eloff [Project Safe Transmute](https://github.com/rust-lang/project-safe-transmute) will eventually make this possible. But I don't know how much time it will take. And if your function cannot verify all preconditions to it, it should be unsafe.

Comment: That Safe Transmute project seems dead. But bytemuck works really well, I switched to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is unsound:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Thingy {
    a: u32,
    b: u16,
}
/// Reinterpret a slice of T as a slice of bytes without copying.
/// Only use with simple copy types like integers, floats, bools, etc. Don't use with structs or enums.
pub fn get_bytes<T: Copy>(array: &[T]) -> &[u8] {
    // Safety: &[u64] can be safely converted to &[u8]
    // (so why doesn't rust have a safe method for this?)
    unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(array.as_ptr() as *const u8, array.len() * std::mem::size_of::<T>()) }
}

fn main() {
    let a = [Thingy {
        a: 0xca_fc_e2_50,
        b: 0x12_34,
    }, Thingy {
        a: 0x98_76_54_32,
        b: 0xca_fc,
    }];
    let b: &[u8] = get_bytes(&a);
    println!("{:?}", b);
    // [80, 226, 252, 202, 52, 18, 0, 0, 50, 84, 118, 152, 252, 202, 0, 0]
}
```

As you can see we can read the unwritten to 0 bytes between the `Thingy`s

If the caller has to hold up some constraints the function should be `unsafe` itself.

Comment: Yes, that's why the comment. I made some changes to make it harder to abuse, what do you think now?